# Shuffle column values but keep the same matrix column ordering

Tags: r, matrix, shuffle

How can I shuffle the values of matrix `m1` across each column:

Initial:

```
m1=cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
```

Do something and:

```
m1=cbind(c(7,5,3),c(4,2,9),c(1,8,6))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `sample` function on each column of your matrix to shuffle it:

```
set.seed(100)
apply(m1, 2, sample)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    8
# [2,]    3    4    9
# [3,]    2    6    7
```

Comment: What I want is to shuffle row values of each column, so for column 1 I shuffle values 1,4 and 7.

Comment: @jpcgandre in the example in your question it looks like you just shuffled each row (perhaps you meant `rbind` instead of `cbind` for the second snippit?). Are you saying you instead want to shuffle row 1 and store it in column 1, shuffle row 2 and store it in column 2, etc? If so, just remove the `t` from my code.

Comment: I've tested it and it does not work. here's the results: `> m1=cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
> m2 <- apply(m1, 1, sample)
> m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    5    6
[2,]    4    8    3
[3,]    1    2    9`

Comment: @jpcgandre I'm sorry -- I'm doing my best to understand what you want but it's very difficult without a more complete example in the question. "How can I shuffle the row values of matrix m1 across each column" is not a sufficient description of what you want, apparently. If you don't want to shuffle the rows, and you don't want to shuffle the rows and then transpose, what exactly is it that you want?

Comment: I want soemthing like `for (i in 1:ncol(m1)) m1[,i] <- m1[order(runif(length(m1[i,]))),i]`.

Comment: @jpcgandre `m1[sample(nrow(m1)), ]` is exactly what I have in my answer. So what's wrong with that?

Comment: @jpcgandre  based on the code you just posted in a comment, it seems like you want to shuffle your columns. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes now it works but your output is not correct. But it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ehm, you mean by row in your example?!

**shuffle a list:**

```
# create a list from 1 to 9
x <- seq(1,9)
# shuffle
x[order(runif(length(x)))]
```

**shuffle rows/columns of a matrix:**

```
# example matrix
m1 <- matrix(x,ncol=3)
# shuffle by row
for (i in 1:nrow(m1)) m1[i,] <- m1[i,order(runif(length(m1[i,])))]
# shuffle by col
for (i in 1:ncol(m1)) m1[,i] <- m1[order(runif(length(m1[i,]))),i]
```

edit: maybe `sample` is better... http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also put `sample` in matrix indices and sample the rows and columns.

To shuffle the entire matrix,

```
> m1[sample(nrow(m1)), sample(ncol(m1))]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    6    9    3
#[2,]    5    8    2
#[3,]    4    7    1
```

Or by row

```
> m1[sample(nrow(m1)), ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    6    9
#[2,]    1    4    7
#[3,]    2    5    8
```

Or by column

```
> m1[,sample(ncol(m1))]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    7    4    1
#[2,]    8    5    2
#[3,]    9    6    3
```

Comment: `m1[sample(nrow(m1)), ]` kinda works but it keeps the same values per row, whereas `for (i in 1:ncol(m1)) m2[,i] <- m1[order(runif(length(m1[i,]))),i]` really shuffles the values within the same column.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want for the result.

Comment: I just want to shuffle the values of matrix `m1` across each column. So shuffle (1,4,7), (2,5,8) and (3,6,9).